# Is it possible to earn the Reversal badge by answering your own question?

Tags: support, badges, reversal-badge

Suppose somebody asks a low quality question and then answers it him/herself giving thorough proper explanation with examples, so that his answer earns 20 votes (under the impression from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17630945/2454376)).

Will the [Reversal http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Reversal&c=g badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) be awarded in this case?

Comment: Wow, I'd hope people would notice what the person did and not reward them with rep/upvotes for answering their *own* bad question, but clearly you've shown an example where people are doing just that. Good question.

Comment: @WendiKidd: One thing to note is that that linked question has 8 downvotes, while the answer has only two downvotes. People downvote questions more readily than answers, since downvotes on answers cost rep.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Currently the answer posted by the OP actually has 4 *up*votes. I'm not saying people need to go out of their way to downvote it, just that if the question was so bad you downvoted it, you probably shouldn't upvote an answer by the same user. But that's just my opinion; others are free to disagree :) (Also the linked question has 4 downvotes. Are you sure we're looking at the same question?)

Comment: Not the *score*, @WendiKidd: the raw number of downvotes (which can be seen, if you have >1K rep, by clicking on the number). At the time we were talking, the question had 8 downvotes, and 4 upvotes. The answer had 2 downvotes and 6 upvotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn There is no mention of this criteria on that duplicate.

Comment: @Danny Right, which is why that answers the question. The list there is all of the triggers and exceptions - we don't need to list out every possible exception.

Comment: According the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/124405/questions-eligible-for-reversal-badge) the criteria have never been met on Stack Overflow or Meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I'm surprised nobody has answered this up until this point. The badge description reads:

> Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score

I see no reason why it *wouldn't* give a Reversal badge. It makes sense to, and there's no qualification against it.

Comment: For future reference: The badge descriptions don't include all the niche rules that govern what *actually* awards the badge. You'd want to reference the [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) for that. A badge like Enlightened, for example, isn't awarded for self-accepts.